# Size class fonts

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I have a view that has 4 rows of 3 buttons each and it is such that all buttons are all of equal height and width. I'm having trouble with setting their font sizes for the iPhone. I'm using the size class "compact width, regular height". If I set the font size to *just* fit for the iPhone 4S or the iPhone 5, it would be too small for the iPhone 6 and 6 plus, and vice versa. I've tried overwriting the fonts entirely programmatically, but it seems the values set in the storyboard always supersede:

```
for button in self.mainMenuButtons {
        button.layer.borderWidth = 4
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor(r: 156, g: 177, b: 215, alpha: 1).CGColor
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 7

        button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Highlighted)

     if let type = phoneType {
            switch type {
            case .iPhone4:
                break
            case .iPhone5:
                button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(1)
            case .iPhone6:
                break
            case .iPhone6P:
                break
            }
        } else { /* iPad */ }
}
```

This is a tried and tested method for recognizing which device the user has. I've set the font to 1 in the code above just to test but surely, the font size is not 1. `mainMenuButtons` is the outlet collection where all the buttons are.

Comment: You should be able to set constraints on the buttons such that their size is not fixed, but scales relative to the size of the screen.

Comment: @Almo I'd love a way to do that...

Comment: You could scale the rect of the buttons, but not the font size.

Comment: "I've tried overwriting the fonts entirely programmatically, but it seems the values set in the storyboard always supersede." This shouldn't happen, what and where is the code you're using to set the button text with correct font?

Comment: 1) Where is this code being executed?  2) Have you confirmed with breakpoints/log that the case is being called if iPhone 5?

Comment: @MichaelSand Confirmed! `println()` called 12 times, as expected.

Comment: And where is it being called? What method of the code calls it, in relation to the view the buttons are in?

Comment: @MichaelSand it's called from the `viewDidLoad()` of the buttons' view controller.

Comment: The problem could be because of how buttons titles are set with setTitle:forState: or setAttributedTitle:forState. Regardless, if you can't change buttons programmatically at all you need to figure out why not.

Comment: @MichaelSand Well, the titles are completely static and are set through interface builder only.

Answer (score 0):

I can change the button font based on the information you've given. Something else must be going on in your code. Maybe the outlet collection? If not connected to the xib/storyboard correctly it can fail silently.

Try creating a new outlet just for one of the buttons to this viewController. If you can modify it with this outlet, then the problem is the connections. If you can't modify it with this newly-created outlet, you have another problem it's not possible to identify on SO.

(To answer your original comment, "it seems the values set in the storyboard always supersede": This is not the case. Once a xib come off of `-initWithCoder:` when the view is loaded, the values aren't modified from storyboard info except by constraints. It's why `-viewDidLoad` is the place for modifying elements that have been loaded, it's done at that point.)

Don't forget to keep checking with breakpoints and/or logs in the switch statement to make sure something else isn't causing the code to not run. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using the buttons for other things in the same for loop and they work perfectly. I will update the question to show the full for loop.

Comment: If you've confirmed with log/breakpoints that this line is getting called in a loop that modifies the other buttons (looks like you'd notice if not) then I don't know what to tell you: Delete derived data, restart Xcode, delete app from simulator/device, etc. Let us know if you solve it.